# Event study: t-statistic for cumulative abnormal returns

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, variance, t-test

I am performing an event study using the market model theory. 
$$
\newcommand{\var}{{\rm var}}
R_{it} = α_i + β_iR_{mt} + ε_{it}
$$
With Abnormal Returns (AR):
$$
AR_{it} = R_{it} − α_i − β_iR_{mτ}
$$
To test the significance of the Cumulative Abnormal Return's (CAR's), one must calculate the variance of the aggregated AR's across firms and then sum this number for each observation in the event window to achieve the variance of the CAR's, and then use the square root of this as the denominator in the t-statistic.

[![Variance of the aggregated AR's][1]][1]
$$
\var(\overline{CAR}(\tau_1, \tau_2)) = \sum_{\tau = \tau_1}^{\tau_2} \var(\overline{AR}_\tau).
$$

However, my problem is that I want to test the CAR's across different points in the event window. That is, from the event date, $t=0$ to one day after the event $t=1$, then also from $t=0$ up to $t=5$.

My question is, does the denominator of the t-statistic for the CAR's change when using a different period? 
$$
\theta_1 = \frac{\overline{CAR}(\tau_1, \tau_2)}{\var(\overline{CAR}(\tau_1, \tau_2))^{1/2}} \sim \mathcal N(0, 1).
$$

For example if testing the CAR's from $t=0$ up to $t=5$, one sums the AR's between these two points for the numerator of the tstat, however for the denominator does one also only sum the variance of the AR's between $t=0$ and $t=5$, or does the denominator remain constant regardless of which points along the event window I am testing and remain the square root of the sum of all the variances across the evt window?

(I tried to add the formula for the variance of aggregated AR's here, but I don't have enough reputation.  Essentially, it's just the rmse^2 of the regression of the market model, summed between firms, for each point in the evt window.)

Comment: Just type the missing equation in. You may be able to figure out how to do it from the ones I did; if not, someone can fix it for you.